# How can I set selectRow on a UIPickerView that is attached to a UITextField

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I have a UITextField which I have attached a UIPickerView.

My UIPickerView has elements

```
var teeUsed = ["Yellow","Blue","Red","Green"]
```

my current setting in the UITextField is Red

When I enter the UITextField my spinner pops up and has Yellow as the first choice. I want RED to the first choice. If I spin all is well, if I just click another field it does not change to Yellow.

I have tried Editing did begin, Touch Down, Primary Action Triggered, but everything is done before the picker is populated so crashed if I try to selectRow

Comment: Post your code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
enum AvailableColors: Int {
    case yellow = 0
    case blue = 1
    case red = 2
    case green = 3

    var colorByIndex: UIColor {
        switch (self) {
        case .yellow:
            return .yellow
        case .blue:
            return .blue
        case .red:
            return .red
        case .green:
            return .green
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    var picker : UIPickerView?
    var selectedIndex = 0

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       //1.init your picker with data.
       // self.picker = UIPickerView()...
       // self.picker.delegate = self
       //2.select predefined index
       self.picker?.selectRow(self.selectedIndex, inComponent: 0, animated: false)

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
       self.selectedIndex = row
       self.textField.backgroundColor = AvailableColors(rawValue: row)?.colorByIndex
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, I was not loading the data before assigning the picker to the UITextField. But my main problem we I tried to use selectedRow when it should have been selectRow